# PHP databases problem with displaying data

Tags: php, database

I'm a beginner to PHP, and I'm looking at displaying info from a database onto a website. When I use a seperate file to include all the database queries it won't display anything on the website, so I have put it all in one file. However, I still cannot get any data from my database to my website? The code is below:

```
<?php 
//inclue_once_'dbh.php';

$dbServername = "localhost";//as it is a localhost server 
$dbUsername = "Harriet"; //user which is accessing database
$dbPassword = "Password1"; //
$dbName = "PHPlessons";
$conn = new mysqli($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}    
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = myqli_num_rows($result);

    if (resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['user_uid'];
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's better to post the code directly in the question ;)

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: `$resultcheck` isn't what you think you are getting... You prob need to do this: `$resultCheck = count(myqli_num_rows($result));`

Comment: @Naruto - `mysqli_num_rows()` returns the number of found rows as an integer so they should not run `count()` on it. The way the OP has done it is correct, except from the missing `s` in `myqli_num_rows()`

Answer (score 2):

You missed a `$`.

Change this:

```
if(resultCheck > 0)
```

with this:

```
if($resultCheck > 0)
```

Also, thanks to [PHP Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), you can write it in a shorter way:

```
if($resultCheck)
```

Try with this code edited:

```
<?php
// first of all, turn on errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dbServername = "localhost";//as it is a localhost server 
$dbUsername = "Harriet"; //user which is accessing database
$dbPassword = "Password1"; //
$dbName = "PHPlessons";
$conn = new mysqli($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}    
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            var_dump($row);
            echo $row['user_uid'];
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive changed this, and it says connected successfully but there is still no data

Comment: @HarrietLarni you must check for the data selected from the database. In the `if($resultCheck)` block add a print to check if the script found data.

Comment: @HarrietLarni did you see my edit?

Comment: @user2342558 thank you, it's working perfect.

Comment: @HarrietLarni You're welcome! Please flag my answer as accepted (with the ✔ below the vote)

Answer (score 0):

You forget s in mysqli replace with below code

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['user_uid'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: As RiggsFolly pointed out. Ideally this should be a comment in the OP as this is a typo error question